# Active connection name - Iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to get the name of internet connection type in iPhone?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Uddhalaka

Answer (score 4):

With the SCNetworkReachability API you can tell if you're in one of three states:

- no network
- cellular network (EDGE or 3G)
- Wifi network

There's no way to distinguish what type of cellular network you're on (EDGE or 3G), only that you're on a cellular network.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html) sample. Figure that it'll use the best available connection (WiFi, 3G, or Edge).